# Internal Server Error 500 mkdir(): Permission denied apache php

Tags: php, apache, centos, mkdir, permission-denied

Apache gives a permission error with php on Centos linux remote server.

I read and tried everything but no luck.

I tried disabling SELinux with setenforce 0;

I tried permissions all 777 and chown -R apache:apache var/www
chown -R root:apache var/ww

also:
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/http/f3

error_log says :

```
/var/www/html/f3/lib/ErrorHandler.php on line 26
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.744772 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] mkdir(): Permission denied
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.745084 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] [f3/lib/base.php:2015] Base->error(500,'mkdir(): Permission denied')
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.745124 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] [f3/lib/base.php:2407] mkdir('/f3/tmp/f3filescache/',493,true)
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.745134 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] [f3/lib/base.php:340] Cache->load('folder=/f3/tmp/f3filescache/',true)
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.745141 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] [f3/index.php:6] Base->set('CACHE','folder=/f3/tmp/f3filescache/')
[Wed Jul 08 14:06:51.746083 2015] [:error] [pid 29288] [client 127.0.0.1:37240] PHP Warning:  file(f3/lib/base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/f3/lib/ErrorHandler.php on line 26
```

I am desperate and furious.
Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "with php on Centos linux remote server"?
Is php (that tries to create the directory) running elsewhere than the filesystem where you want to create this dir? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I read `mkdir('/f3/tmp/f3filescache/',493,true)`. Do you have a slash (/) at the begin of your directory name ? This would be an absolute path... wihch of course is not writable

Comment: If you are using PHP 7.0.5 or lower then install PHP 7.0.10. It helped me in similar case.